# how to omit extra bits in a file?

Tags: c++, mfc, cstring

I want  to omit extra bit in txt file.eg ....`ÿ 0111111110111101100011011010010001` in this string we want to omit extra bit `ÿ`  which is appeared when we save a binary string.  Save fun is as follow. please help me.

```
void LFSR_ECDlg::Onsave() 
{
    this->UpdateData();

    CFile bitstream;
    char strFilter[] = { "Stream Records (*.mpl)|*.mpl| (*.pis)|*.pis|All Files (*.*)|*.*||" };

    CFileDialog FileDlg(FALSE, ".mpl", NULL, 0, strFilter);



    if( FileDlg.DoModal() == IDOK )
    {
        if( bitstream.Open(FileDlg.GetFileName(), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite) == FALSE )
            return;
        CArchive ar(&bitstream, CArchive::store);


        CString txt;
        txt="";
        txt.Format("%s",m_B);//by ANO
        AfxMessageBox (txt);//by ANO
        txt=m_B;//by ANO
        ar <<txt;//by ANO

        ar.Close();
    }
    else
        return;

    bitstream.Close();
}
```

Comment: I don't use the Microsoft libraries, so I probably can't help you, but I suggest you simplify this code (remove things like the `CFileDialog` which are not necessary to the problem) and tell us what 'm_B' is. This will help us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Beta: You know m_B is an LPCTSTR because of %s.

Comment: @Billy: Actually you _hope_ it's such a beast.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `CFile::typeBinary` to `CFile::Open` when you construct `bitstream`. Otherwise check what is creating the CString (`m_B`). The extra character you are seeing looks like a Byte Order Mark....

Answer (score 0):

void LFSR_ECDlg::Onsave() 
{
this->UpdateData();

```
CFile bitstream;
char strFilter[] = { "Stream Records (*.mpl)|*.mpl| (*.pis)|*.pis|All Files (*.*)|*.*||" };

CFileDialog FileDlg(FALSE, ".mpl", NULL, 0, strFilter);
```

//insertion//by TTT

```
CFile cf_object;
if( FileDlg.DoModal() == IDOK ){
cf_object.Open( FileDlg.GetFileName(), CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeWrite);
//char szText[100];
//strcpy(szText, "File Write Test");
    CString txt;
    txt="";
    txt.Format("%s",m_B);//by ANO
    AfxMessageBox (txt);//by ANO
int mB_size=m_B.GetLength();
cf_object.Write (m_B,mB_size);
```

}